# Pasted code couldn't work in a new project ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Today, I copied a function codes in an old project to paste in a new project, the following is the related codes

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

When I debug the project, it's never been called.Then related codes and storyboard is checked, nothing wrong, so I deleted the pasted functions codes, and wrote the codes word by word; debug, run and it's been called.

The other pasted codes were well run and called. Only this function had an issue.

After all, I studied the issue, and cannot find why it happened.

Please, help me to solve "the paste codes cannot be called".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please paste all delegate methods

Comment: Try @Chris Loonam 's answer.

Comment: machines do not suffer or exercise choice they do exactly whats to be done error must be on your part you may try clearing derived data though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a capitalization issue in the method name. change  ***tableview:*** into 
***tableView:***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

should be this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Yes, the capitalization issue, my mistake not XCode's.  Thank you~~

Answer (score 1):

Oh, your god, I think you must have not connect the table view datasource to the target controller.

```
yourTableView.dataSource = self
```

`self` is your target controller that implements the `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: It's my mistake about spelling. Thanks.